# Debugging IronPython in Visual Studio 2010 - Source lines not synchronized

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ironpython, visual-studio-debugging

I use VS 2010 to debug a single IronPython module. Everything works great. I can set breakpoints, watch local variables, etc. The only annoyance (which is serious) is that yellow arrow that marks the current step in the debugger is not synchronized with the real line being edited. Did anyone run into this issue?

I created an IronPython project through Visual Studio to make sure. I don't miss some important setting, but to no avail.

Pyramid Newbie

Update: 
Ok. Problem solved. I had a bunch of Python interpreters installed and the default interpreter was Python 3.2. I switched the default interpreter to IronPython 2.7 and everything is peachy now. The settings is in Tools|Options|Python Tools|Interpreter Options|Default Interpreter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Problem solved. I had a bunch of Python interpreters installed and the default interpreter was Python 3.2. I switched the default interpreter to IronPython 2.7 and everything is peachy now. The settings is in Tools|Options|Python Tools|Interpreter Options|Default Interpreter